# How to filter table by two columns

Tags: powerbi

I have the following table:

| ID | TEST_ID | Component | ComponentInfo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Test 1 | Info |
| 2 | 5 | Test 1 | AB 2 |
| 3 | 5 | Test 1 | XY |
| 4 | 5 | Test X | Info 2 |
| 5 | 5 | Test X | Info 1 |
| 6 | 5 | Test Y | Info 2 |
| 7 | 6 | Test 1 | Info 2 |
| 8 | 7 | ABC | Info 1 |
| 9 | 8 | XYZ | Info 2 |
| 9 | 9 | XYZ | Info 2 |

I like to get the following output:

| TEST_ID | Component |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Test 1 |
| 5 | Test X |
| 5 | Test Y |
| 6 | Test 1 |
| 7 | ABC |
| 8 | XYZ |
| 9 | XYZ |

I think it would be nice to realize it in the data transformation part. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press strg select TEST_ID and Component, right click then remove duplicates

= Table.Distinct(#"changed type", {"TEST_ID", "Component"})

Thats what I need! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any filtering in your "question"; Rather, removing redundant columns and leaving unique values.

M language statement:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTIF4pDU4hIFEMczLy1fKVYnWskIXcbRScEILGOMLhMRCRY3QRaPgJoF1WOKVc4QLGeGLBeJqs8cyDVDdx9UzgLINQc7zBnVQEsg1wLsrihUHSAJSwyJWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, TEST_ID = _t, Component = _t, ComponentInfo = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"TEST_ID", Int64.Type}, {"Component", type text}, {"ComponentInfo", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"ID", "ComponentInfo"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’ll have a look in to it! The goal is not hiding columns, I can ignore the values like ComponentInfo and so on.  I need only one of multiple Test_ID and Component pairs, maybe the first row and skip the rest if available.